# python3 - bad practice to use assert?

Tags: python, python-3.x, security

I have a python3 script which uses simple assert statement to compare the values of two variables.

```
assert response['checksum'] == checksum
```

A code analysis tool called bandit flagged this as bad practice and less protected. 
https://bandit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/plugins/b101_assert_used.html

Is using assert really bad practice and less secure?

Answer (score 4):

You gave the answer yourself in the link:

> It was discovered that some projects used assert to enforce interface constraints. However, assert is removed with compiling to optimised byte code (python -o producing *.pyo files).

So if a library relies on `assert` to enforce some kind of validation and I were to use it with `py2exe` or some similar tool, there's a big chance the resulting code will be missing the assertions **and** failing or skipping said validations.That's why you should only use `assert` in test code and the like.